# How to point example.com/directory to another EC2 instance with SSL?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have all my website files - example.com - on my EC2 server (Ubuntu and Apache) with SSL on EC2 instance 1. I want example.com/blog to go to another EC2 instance - EC2 instance 2. How can I do that with SSL?

I'm using Ubuntu and Apache and Route 53. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do this is with CloudFront, described in [this answer at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/729706/153161), where you can use path patterns to determine which URLs will be handed off to which server.

Another is an Application Load Balancer (ELB/2.0), which allows the instance to be selected based on [path rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html).

Both of these solutions support free SSL certificates from Amazon Certificate Manager.

Or, you can use [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) in the Apache config on the main example.com web server to relay all requests matching specific paths oer to a different instance.

**You cannot accomplish this with Route 53 alone, because DNS does not work at the path level.**  This is not a limitation in Route 53, it's a fundamental part of how DNS works.

Answer (score 1):

You quickly and easily achieve this by using nginx reverse proxy. Your ssl will still be managed and offloaded on the ELB level. That is listener 443 =>> 80

1) install nginx

```
yum install nginx
```

2) add to nginx config

```
upstream server1 {

        server  127.0.0.1:8080;

}

upstream server2 {

        server  server2_IP_address_here:8080;


}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://server1;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
       location /blog {

                proxy_pass http://server1;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;  
      }              

}
```